# Python script to Get every texts and tags within a specified xml tag

Tags: python, xml

I have to get every tags and values within the specific tag.

For Example:

```
<xml>
<new>
<post>
<text>New Text</text> 
<category>New Category</category>
</post>
</new>
<specific>
<line> Line.... </line> 
New Line ends ......!!!!
</specific>
```

Python script:

```
root = et.fromstring('Xml from path')
target_elements = root.findall('.//post')
```

If I give  tag means , I need the output as :

Expected Output:

```
<text>New Text</text>
<category>New Category</category>
```

For  tag:

Output:

```
<line> Line.... </line> 
 New Line ends ......!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the `</xml>` tag is missing at the end of your XML fragment.*

```
content = """\
<xml>
<new>
<post>
<text>New Text</text> 
<category>New Category</category>
</post>
</new>
<specific>
<line> Line.... </line> 
New Line ends ......!!!!
</specific>
</xml>"""
```

There is no real difficulties using [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML(content)

for elem in root.findall(".//post"):
    for child in iter(elem):
        print(child.tag + ": " + child.text)
```

If you want to output XML fragments as string, simply use `tostring` function:

```
for elem in root.findall(".//post"):
    for child in iter(elem):
        print(etree.tostring(child, encoding="unicode", with_tail=False))
```

You'll get:

```
<text>New Text</text>
<category>New Category</category>
```

To go further, read the online tutorial: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you.. But If I give for elem in root.findall(".//specific") means the result should be : <line> Line.... </line> 
New Line ends ......!!!! ..Bt the above code gives only <line> Line.... </line> 
Could you please help me to find out this ?

Comment: Read the doc: "New Line ends ......!!!!" Is a `tail` of the `line` element. To display it, change into `with_tail=True`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = '''<xml>
<new>
<post>
<text>New Text</text>
<category>New Category</category>
</post>
</new>
<specific>
<line> Line.... </line>
New Line ends ......!!!!
</specific>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc)
print(soup.find_all('post'))
```

Output:

```
[<post>
<text>New Text</text>
<category>New Category</category>
</post>]
```